# phi(P*Q) = (P-1) * (Q-1)

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

I was trying to understand RSA when I encountered the Euler Function. I do understand this: $\phi(P)$, where $P$ is a prime is $P-1$.

However it seems that for a number $N$ such at $N=P\cdot Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are non-equal primes:

\begin{equation}
    \phi(P\cdot Q) = (P-1)\cdot(Q-1)
\end{equation}

I'm having trouble understanding why that is so. Could someone point me toward the proof of the same?

Comment: How would one know that the totient function is multiplicative as mentioned in the answer above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a special case of a more general property of the [Euler totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function): it is a [multiplicative function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function), meaning that, for any two [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) numbers $p$ and $q$, $\phi(pq) = \phi(p)\phi(q)$.

The special case where $p$ and $q$ are (distinct) primes is easy to prove.
By definition, $\phi(n)$ gives the number of positive integers coprime to and smaller than $n$, i.e. the number of integers $k$ satisfying $0 < k < n$ and $\gcd(k,n) = 1$.

Since $p$ and $q$ are the prime factors of $pq$, an integer $k$ is coprime to $pq$ if and only if it isn't a multiple of either $p$ or $q$.  In the range $0 < k < pq$ there are $p-1$ distinct multiples of $q$, and $q-1$ distinct multiples of $p$, and a bit of thought shows that these two sets cannot overlap, as any positive number that was a multiple of both $p$ and $q$ would have to be at least as large as $pq$.

Thus, out of the total $pq-1$ integers $k$ in the range $0 < k < pq$, all but $(p-1) + (q-1)$ are coprime to $pq$, and so $$\begin{aligned}\phi(pq) &= (pq-1) - (p-1) - (q-1) \\ &= pq - p - q + 1 \\ &= (p-1)(q-1).\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Great answer! I just want to note that the math could be simplified by considering the range $1 \leq k \leq pq$, which is what Euler's totient function considers per the Wikipedia article. In the range $[1, pq]$, there are $pq$ integers. Of those, 1) $p$ integers are distinct multiples of $q$, 2) $q$ integers are distinct multiples of $p$, and 3) exactly one integer ($pq$ itself) is a multiple of both. By the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of $k$s that are NOT a multiple of $p$ or $q$ is $pq - p - q + 1$.

Answer (score 6):

A very simple explanation is that a prime number is co-prime with every number below it:

$$ϕ(P) = (P−1)$$

Because Euler Totient Function is multiplicative function, this means that:

$$ϕ(pq)=ϕ(p)ϕ(q)$$

Which can be written as:

$$ϕ(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$$

I hope this helps. Otherwise, just look at Ilmari Karonens answer.

Comment: Simple equations like yours are pretty easy to format; I just added `$$` around what you'd written to trigger display math mode. For more advanced tricks, see [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).